# AEM instance is not getting started with start command

Tags: aem

I am working with AEM6.3 on Redhat linux server. I have one author and one publish instance on two different linux servers.
I am able to start my author instance using the start command (./start) under **crx-quickstart/bin** folder.
But my publish instance is not getting started using the **./start** command. I am getting "**Sling already active in /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart**
" error in the **stdout.log** file as below-

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
06.09.2017 46:24:38.789 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=crx-quickstart (command line)
06.09.2017 46:24:38.789 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/277.0.0.9:36038] /277.0.0.9:44314>status
06.09.2017 46:24:38.790 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/277.0.0.9:36038] /277.0.0.1:44314<OK
06.09.2017 46:24:38.791 *INFO * [main] Sent 'status' to /277.0.0.9:36038: OK
06.09.2017 46:24:38.792 *ERROR* [main] Sling already active in /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart
```

I can see some posts with the same error mentioned, but they are for the windows system.

How can I resolve this in the **linux**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [ControlListener.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/base/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/app/ControlListener.java) which is referred in the [sling launchpad documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/the-sling-launchpad.html)

specifically, the `listen` method:

```
boolean listen() {
    final File configFile = getConfigFile();
    if (configFile.canRead() && statusServer() == 0) {
        // server already running, fail
        Main.error("Sling already active in " + this.slingMain.getSlingHome(), null);
        return false;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

the `listen` method calls `getConfigFile`method:

```
private File getConfigFile() {
    final File configDir = new File(this.slingMain.getSlingHome(), "conf");
    return new File(configDir, "controlport");
}
```

So basically, by default (with default AEM installation) it will look for the file: `crx-quickstart/conf/controlport` (somewhat documented in the [sling launchpad documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/the-sling-launchpad.html)) if it finds and can read it, then it will fail as it thinks there is a running instance. My assumption is that you've stopped a running instance by killing its process or an unexpected shutdown happened.

**either way, try this:**

1. copy the file: `crx-quickstart/conf/controlport` to a different location (as a backup)
2. Delete the file `crx-quickstart/conf/controlport`
3. run your start command

This is hypothetical as I could not reproduce, but looking at launchpad code, this seems like it will fix your issue.